# iPhone image gallery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-gallery

I am looking for a simple picture gallery for iPhone (photo viewer). I was using  [EasyGallery](https://github.com/dev5tec/EasyGallery.git) on iOS 4 and I am having some issues with this gallery under iOS 5. The Gallery from Three20 is too complex for me and has a lot of Features I do not need (loading pictures from the internet -> I just need support for local pictures). I need to show pictures from the app bundle, not from the photo library.

1) EasyGallery was working under iOS 4, but not under iOS 5. If someone has chaged its source code so that it is now working with iOS 5, please poste your code here.

2) [FGallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) does not work when the view is presented modally. And that's my case. So, if someone has adapted the source code from FGallery to work modally, please also poste your code here.

I've tried to change the source code from 1 and 2 myself, but I did not have success. Does someone know a simple ready to use image gallery for the iPhone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FGallery is quite good. The test application was a little buggy when I tried last time, and I had some issues customizing the look, but yes, it is simple and readily usable.

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

Comment: Thanks barley. I've spent the last hours trying to use the FGallery and it works very well when you have a navigation controller. But I need to present the view modally, and FGallery dows not work whe it is presented modally. Very weird actually. I've spent hours changing the source code but I had no success. Thanks for your clue anyway ;)

Answer (score 16):

[MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

[KTPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser)

[EGOPhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer)

I've tried all of them, and find they are similar (as they are replicating Apple's one), all 3 load images asynchronously, with caching.

Comment: Why -ve vote for this answer? Is it just because he posted only project names?

Comment: `Does someone know a simple ready to use image gallery for the iPhone?`

I thought I was answering the question LOL?

Comment: If SO would add FB kind of 'Like' button (instead of 'great comment') then you would have lots of likes.

Comment: But still it would be useful with some comments. Why should we really use these. Do you have any experiences with any of these?

Comment: I've tried all of them, and find they are similar (as they are replicating Apple's one), all 3 load images asynchronously, with caching.

Answer (score 3):

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

and see delegate methods [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html)

Comment: I do not want to show pictures from the photo library but from the application bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this custom photo gallery Video Demo: http://screencast.com/t/7ixTAAWGtt

Comment: What are the benefits of this photo gallery? A little bit more comprehensive information here would be really useful.